# Windows PowerShell ISE doesn't promt for input

Tags: windows, powershell, mercurial, cmd

I am using console as my tool for managing mercurial repositories. Wtih classic **cmd** or **Console2** I type:

```
hg in
```

And console prompts something like:

```
D:\workspace\someproject>hg in
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: xorty
password:
```

And obviously, I type password.

But when I type "hg in" in powershell console, it doesn't prompt anything. It just keeps saying this:
`Running script / selection. Press Ctrl + Break to stop`

Can I make PowerShell ISE behave like classic console, or this isn't the way PowerShell is meant to work?

Comment: Have you tried the PowerShell command prompt or just the ISE? manojlds answer seems correct to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The PowerShell ISE indeed [does not support console applications that require interactive input](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/02/04/console-application-non-support-in-the-ise.aspx). The linked blog entry details options how to deal with that.

Since the PowerShell ISE is not a console, normal console applications cannot do everything they're used to, while of course PowerShell cmdlets can work just fine, since several things are dependent on the PowerShell host application (you get a graphical prompt with Read-Host, for example).

Console2 emulates a normal console by keeping the actual console around in a hidden window and polling it repeatedly for changes and, correspondingly, sending input to that window.

Comment: Thanx for explanation, it's shame though :/

Answer (score 4):

Powershell ISE ( integrated scripting environment ) is not the standard Powershell console. The ISE, like the name suggests, is a pretty basic GUI based script writing tool and doesn't support interactive console applications ( try just `cmd` on the ISE console and see the error message)

Open powershell.exe, and run the command that you want. It will behave pretty much like cmd. Or alternatively, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in the ISE and run the command there.