# How to interact with the console (input/output) running a Perl program on "Windows Power Shell ISE"?

Tags: windows, perl, powershell, io

I have a certain Perl program that I need to run on Windows 7 "Power Shell ISE" (since the regular MS Windows console does not support many Unicode fonts, and PS-ISE does, and I need to process Unicode files on Windows, using Perl).
When running a Perl program from the regular cmd console, you go, for example,
 `"Perl hello.pl"`;
 the program runs, and if you print something, let's say 
 `print "Hello world\n";`
 it gets printed in the cmd box.
How can I do it in PS-ISE? In PS-ISE, when I go:  
`"Perl hello.pl"`
 it hangs. PS-ISE says: "Running script/selection. Press Ctrl+Break to stop", but it doesn't print "Hello world".
(Next, I also need to accept input from STDIN).
Important note: it's "Power shell ISE", not: "Power Shell".

Comment: Is `">Perl .."` a typo, or are you really trying to redirect output to `Perl`?

Comment: No redirection, straight command. (I wanted to show the shell prompt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I elaborated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8332844/73070) already, the PowerShell ISE does not support interactive Windows console applications.

Note also, that the console settings (and in particular the fonts) are totally irrelevant when *processing* Unicode text. Displaying is another matter. But processing doesn't sound like that to me.

Since you asked about Console in the mail, [here it is](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), as a web search might have told you (and I thought I made my stance on personal mails originating from SO users clear).

Comment: I raised you answer by 1 and accepted the answer. By the way, in your "another answer" that your refer to, you mentioned "Console2", while in the SourceForge project it shows up as "Console" project, or Console-2.00 etc., so it's not straightforward to find it on a search engine. You also mention that you can run Console2 as a cmdlet? Can you explain how to do it?

Comment: Where do I mention that you could run Console2 as a cmdlet? That's news to me, especially if I have allegedly written that.