# Powershell ISE / SSH - won´t ask passphrase

Tags: windows, git, powershell, github, ssh

MySystem: Windows 7 - 64bit - Powershell vers. 4

I started working Git. 
Installed Git, msysgit and for powershell I am using posh-git.

No issues with Git itself - 
but I need to run "console-apps" (C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin) like SSH.

Via ISE

- `SSH (without parameter)`: default usage message - which is ok
- `SSH -T git@gitserver`  : nothing happens - so let´s go deeper:
- `ssh -v git@gitserver`  : runs until "debug1: read PEM private key done: type " - **nothing else**

  - other way to open it via ISE (just to test general behaviour with other app)
    `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin> ii .\sh.exe`
    this will open a new cmd window with the same feedback like below.

Via Powershell Console:

- `SSH (without parameter)`: default usage message - which is ok
- `SSH -T git@gitserver`  : Welcome message (after entering passphrase)
- `ssh -v git@gitserver`  : runs until "debug1: read PEM private key done: type " - ** PS Console asks entering psw for passphrase **

  --> so the ISE won´t show at least the password question...

As I just documented it step-by-step on a other system I know that it should work in general.

ANY idea ? 
I had already reinstalled Git
I found no way to reinstall / repair Windows Management Framework 4.0 or ISE

thx in advance

Comment: All I can do, is to confirm that  OpenSSL client from Git  does not work with PowerShell_ISE. It will not pass any prompt to the ISE host screen. Not even `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`. Read more about it here [Windows PowerShell ISE doesn't promt for input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332805/windows-powershell-ise-doesnt-promt-for-input)

Comment: @JanChrbolka: thx for your response - issue not solved but this is related to ISE - his links explain details!