# Password promt not displayed in PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have an executable from the android SDK: keytool.exe
I call it as following:

```
keytool.exe -list -keystore mykeystore.ks
```

When executed in cmd, the executable promts for the keystore password. 
When executed in PowerShell ISE - nothing happens.

Why is the password promt not displayed inside powershell?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to run this in PowerShell or PowerShell ISE?

Comment: Looks like it is not supported in powershell ISE. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332805/windows-powershell-ise-doesnt-promt-for-input

Comment: The ISE has some very odd and flakey limitations and behaviors. To be honest I rarely use it since it doesn't accurately represent the way the script will run anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the powershell ISE does not support user promt (see the comments). Its a pitty, since it could have been a really good tool